# Show that every Carmichael number is odd.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I wanted you guys to tell me if my proof is correct:

By definition, $a^n ≡ a \bmod(n)$, if $n$ is Carmichael.

Assume $n$ is even. Then $n = 2m$, for some number $m$.

Then $a^{2m} ≡ a \bmod(2m)$.
Since $2m$ is congruent to $\bmod(2m)$,
$a^{2m} ≡ a^0 ≡ 1 ≡ a \bmod(2m)$.

Then, $a ≡ 1 \bmod(n)$ implies that $a ≡ 1, 1+n, 1+2n,...,1+(n-1)n$.
But since $n$ is even, by assumption, the last term becomes $1+(2m-1)\cdot2m ≡ 1+2m$.
But this term is odd for any $m$, hence there is a contradiction and $n$ is odd.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $a=n-1$.

**Remark:** There is no progress towards a proof in the OP.

Comment: I saw the proof for a ≡ n-1 but I always wondered why n-1?

Comment: Because $n-1$ is "really" $-1$, and $-1$ to an even power is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no this is not correct.
Your line "Since $2m$ is congruent to $\bmod(2m)$..." does not make sense. Replace $2m$ with $n$ and you will see that you can literally write $n$ is congruent to $\bmod(n)$, therefore $a^n ≡ 1 \bmod(n)$, which is not right.

Additionally, one detail you are missing is that $a^n ≡ a \bmod(n)$ is true for numbers between $1$ and $n$. So, writing $a ≡ 1, 1+n,...$ does not make sense either.

To prove that $n$ is odd, use the Korselt's criterion.